# Laravel Mix 404 on Incorrect Hash

Tags: laravel, versioning, laravel-mix

Is it possible to redirect a request to 404 if the Mix version hash is incorrect i.e not found in the mix-manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need such a behaviour, but I would something like:

```
try {
  mix('yourfile');
} catch (Exception $e) {
  abort(404);
}
```

Comment: eg myscript.js?id=1 , If 1 is incorrect it returns 404